# Contacts added from UWP app deleted after uninstall

Tags: uwp, contacts

I had run the sample app [Connect your app to actions on a contact card](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/integrating-with-contacts).

I uninstalled the sample app after creating test contacts, then the contacts are lost.

How can I create permanent contacts?

Answer (score 0):

No contacts are really permanent. Contacts are associated with a contact list which are associated with an application. In the case of some email accounts, contacts are associated with that account.

The various contacts from various accounts and various apps can be linked if they represent the same person. The closest thing to a permanent contact is to create a contact in the Microsoft Account which the Windows device is running and replicate the information that applies in the Microsoft Account contact and link the two contacts.

However, once you delete the app or email account, you will still lose the information for that app or email account. I know it's not a great solution.